# Blank page instead of setup When install Magento2

Tags: magento2, setup

Blank page instead of setup When install Magento2

**Error :** [Here](http://www.screencast.com/t/EHe2lTii6W0)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Follow this Commands :**

```
php bin/magento setup:install --base-url="YourSiteUrl" --db-host="DBhost" --db-name="DBName" --db-user="DBuser" --db-password="DBpassword" --admin-firstname="admin" --admin-lastname="admin" --admin-email="AdminEmail" --admin-user="admin" --admin-password="admin@123" --language="en_US" --currency="USD" --timezone="America/Chicago" --use-rewrites="1" --backend-frontname="admin"
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
php bin/magento cache:flush
```