# The magento2 installation stops at 71%

Tags: magento2

The local installation magento2 ran over 66 and got stuck at 71[image]

Comment: can you please install using command line
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/231475/blank-page-instead-of-setup-when-install-magento2/231478#231478

Comment: please open that console log to review error

Answer (score 0):

Please check below link and then try to install. Also Change in php.ini.

```
max_execution_time = 1800
max_input_time = 1800
memory_limit = 1024M
```

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/prereq/apache.html http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/system-requirements.html